# Do financiers request IDERA's for small aircraft?

Tags: economics

Do financiers request IDERA's for small aircraft, or just large ones registered under the CTC?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! It might be helpful if you can explain what IDERA and CTC are.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly just a little bit of background. IDERA's - Irrevocable Deregistration and Export Request Authorizations - are issued under the Cape Town Convention (or Cape Town Treaty). This is a voluntary convention that countries can subscribe to. It essentially provides more assurance for financiers, who can therefore provide lower interest rates to aircraft buyers.

The [FAA states the eligibility requirements](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/cape_town_treaty/)  for IDERA's, which, for fixed-wing aircraft, need to be able to carry at least 8 people, or can carry goods in excess of 2750 kilograms (6050 pounds). So most aircraft considered 'small' probably would not be covered.